# how do i calculate test val accuracy in cnn network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

```
model = model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), \
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', \
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=32, 
                        epochs=20,
                        validation_data= (X_val, y_val), verbose=True)

Epoch 20/20
256/256 [==============================] - 36s 142ms/step - loss: 3.2233 - accuracy: 0.3038 - val_loss: 4.6129 - val_accuracy: 0.1223
```

this is my train, validation accuracy.
then I try to predict test using this model.

```
pred = model.predict(x_test)
print(sum(pred)/len(y_test))

[0.00475577 0.00301154 0.00287763 0.00612131 0.0036318  0.00388619
 0.00493319 0.0042463  0.00228897 0.00665664 0.00334664 0.00361817
 0.00434758 0.00653938 0.00231704 ......
```

How can I calculate my test accuracy?

```
pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(pred[0])
print(len(pred))
print(y_test[0])
print(len(pred))

result:
[0.00649052 0.0015973  0.00097144 0.01938977 0.0027661  0.00357595
 0.0020057  0.00599558 0.00418835....
2048
209
2048
```

that is my pred value and y_test value.

Comment: You could do `sum(pred==y_test)/len(y_test)` to get a quick result. Check out [`model.evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate), though. It might serve you better in the long run.

Comment: yes, i tried it before, but , i got this error, TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable. what does it mean?

Comment: It means `pred` is not what I thought :) You will have to check out the `evaluate` function but I can't help you there...

Comment: is that mean there is no correct label for pred.... the accuracy is zeo....

Comment: Please post the result of a *single* prediction, i.e. your `pred[0]`, along with your `y_test[0]`.

Comment: You need to first convert your probability predictions into class predictions (integer labels) by taking the argmax, and only then you can compute accuracy with the code above.

Comment: @desertnaut i updated the question, could u have a look?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy i follow what said,```  
pred = model.predict(X_test)
indexes = tf.argmax(pred, axis=1)
print(sum(indexes == y_test)/ len(y_test)),``` I get another error, which is TypeError: Cannot convert 0 to EagerTensor of dtype bool